# Changing slider img opacity using simple JS

Tags: javascript

How i can add some fade effect by changingimg opacity using only simple JS(not Jquery)?

```
var step = 12;
var total = 60;

function slide(x) {
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName("clickSliderimg");
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        step = step + x;
        if (step > total) {
            step = 12;
        }
        if (step < 12) {
            step = total;
        }
        image[i].src = "css/images/img" + step + ".jpg";
    };
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the library simple.js or vanilla (plain) JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580105/javascript-img-slider-with-fade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reduce the opacity and put it in a loop that repeats itself until the picture has opacity 0, then set display to none:

```
var img = document.getElementById('id of image to be faded').style;
  img.opacity = 1; 
(function fade(){(img.opacity-=.1)<0?img.display="none":setTimeout(fade,40)})();
```

Comment: Thanks,dear friend, for the useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("clickSliderimg"), function(el) {
   el.style.transition = 'opacity 4s';
   el.style.opacity = 0.5;
}
```

You should use CSS animations and transitions for simple animations and trigger them eg. by adding class to element.

Animating elements using JS tends to draw battery life, pollutes your code and is unmaintainable.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reasons I would suggest you to use a mix of Javascript and CSS.

So you can define some CSS classes such as:

```
img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: opacity .3s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s linear;
}

.visible {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And then you can simply add / remove the "visible" class to your images.

```
# Add class
image.className += " visible";

# Remove class
image.className.replace( /(?:^|\s)visible(?!\S)/g , '' )
```